# Atualizando Apk no Google Play

Tags: android

Fiz algumas modificações em um app que foi iniciado por outro desenvolvedor. As modificações deram tudo certo e agora quero publicar no Google Play. Segui o tutorial http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html Altero a versão depois adotei principalmente a parte que usa o `ADT - > Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package` - Crio uma nova keystore - Assino - Alinho e beleza gero Apk.

Mas o Google Play me dá uma mensagem dizendo que os certificados SHA1 estão diferentes.

Tenho que gerar o apk com a mesma keystore que foi criada pelo desenvolvedor inicial? E se ele perdeu o arquivo o que posso fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Tenho que gerar o apk com a mesma keystore que foi criada pelo desenvolvedor inicial?

Sim.

> E se ele perdeu o arquivo o que posso fazer?

Então a única maneira é fazer upload de um novo aplicativo e deletar o anterior. Note que eles serão aplicativos diferentes, o que significa que os usuários terão que fazer outra instalação.

Comment: Só para complementar, você também perderá todas as estatísticas geradas para o aplicativo que foi perdido a chave.